# change header of csv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

hi I am writing data on csv using python my code is something like this

```
name_keys =['Record_1', 'Record_2', 'Random_Name'] 

header_names =  ['Record 1', 'Record 2', 'Random Name'] 

with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=name_keys)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

issue is my **header_names** are suppose to be bit diff from  **name_keys** . so how I can achieve this   ? And I don't want to use pandas here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
    writer.writeheader()
```

Fake a row of data:

```
    writer.writerow(dict(zip(name_keys,header_names)))
```

Comment: thanks sir , worked for me